# Abstract methods in c#

Tags: c#, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I honestly don't know why this is throwing me off.

```
 public abstract class BankAccount
    {
        private string accNo;
        private double balance;


        public abstract void MakeWithdrawal(string acc);
        public abstract void MakeDeposit(double dep);
```

The above code is throwing this error:

> BankAccount.MakeWithdrawal()' is abstract but it is contained in
>   non-abstract class 'Worksheet7.BankAccount'

This is even though i declared the class as abstract.
Is there something I'm missing here or a perquisite in visual studio I'm missing?

Comment: The code you've posted is correct - the problem must be somewhere else

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that you have some other class called `BankAccount` in the `Worksheet7` namespace which is not defined as `abstract`. The following code compiles just fine:

```
public abstract class BankAccount
{
    private string accNo;
    private double balance;

    public abstract void MakeWithdrawal(string acc);
    public abstract void MakeDeposit(double dep);
}
```

So the error message is not on this class. It is on another class with the same name defined in a different namespace.